# "Deprecation Notice" error in PhpMyAdmin with ubuntu 20.04, php8.0

Tags: phpmyadmin

**I'am getting error when i login to phpmyadmin**

Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Di/ReflectorItem.php#82
Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Di/ReflectorItem.php#50: PhpMyAdmin\Di\ReflectorItem->_resolveArgs(
array,
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Di/FactoryItem.php#27: PhpMyAdmin\Di\ReflectorItem->invoke(array)
./libraries/classes/Di/Container.php#62: PhpMyAdmin\Di\FactoryItem->get(array)
./libraries/classes/Di/AliasItem.php#44: PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container->get(
string 'PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController',
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Di/Container.php#62: PhpMyAdmin\Di\AliasItem->get(array)
./db_structure.php#35: PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container->get(
string 'DatabaseStructureController',
array,
)

Answer (score 30):

You can also disable notifications and warnings adding this line to config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Source: [PMA Docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SendErrorReports)

Comment: since the question is actually about "deprecation warning" which disturb experience after upgrage php (not error), this part is the correct solution. Since this solution is like "turning off" the warning mesage.

Comment: This worked for me in `ubuntu 20.04`. I upgraded my php version from `php7.4` to `php8.1`, after that I faced this error in phpmaydmin. Then I  added this line `$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';`  to end of this file  `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely caused by using PHP 8 and PHPMyAdmin < v5 either upgrade you PHPMyAdmin to 5.0 or higher or downgrade your PHP to 7

Comment: this is not a solution. I am using php v8 because my application need it.

Comment: @HarshalLonare upgrade phpMyAdmin to the latest version. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 uses PHP 7.1 and phpMyAdmin 4.9.10 uses PHP 5.5 to 7.4
You can see that info here:
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

I have installed 4.9.5 with apache, so what I did was install PHP7.4 and php7.4-fpm, then I modified the phpMyAdmin apache config file to indicate that it should work with PHP7.4

Install php7.4-fpm:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fcgid
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enmod actions alias proxy_fcgi fcgid
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Modify phpMyAdmin apache config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

After `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` paste:

```
<FilesMatch \.php> # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

You can restart apache again and that's it. Good luck!

Comment: With me, the phpMyAdmin apache config file is located at: `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: I don't think this is the solution since this solution suggest to downgrade to php 7. The title already said it uses php8 which is newer.

Answer (score 0):

Because 5.0 series is ended and 5.1 will be out next this will not be fixed.
5.1 has a new DI system and the classes mentioned in the output do not exist anymore.
But you can download the latest version in development (phpMyAdmin 5.1+snapshot) and the DI errors should be gone :)

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16268

Answer (score 0):

I've got a WAMPSERVER installed and what cleared those notices for me was updating phpmyadmin to 5.1.3 that supported PHP 8